# automatic ID generation in SQL & c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am developing an application where I need to generate automatic ID depending on type & it's abbreviation & then a seq no. For example : If animal type is cat I need to use code name CT for it & then no 001. so ID wil be CT-001, CT-002 . for animal type dog it will be DG-001, DG-002 etc. The type it is geeting from web form .

I am trying to achieve this in following way: First I am having two tables . first one for Type & it's code_name. 2nd one is having code_name, seq_No & the generated ID. then writing a stored procedure like below:

```
@X= Select code_name from Tb_first where type = 'input from from';

@Y = Select max(seq_No) from Tb_Second where code_name= @X;

@Y= @Y+1;

@z= @X + convert (String, @Y)

insert (code_name, seq_No, ID) into Tb_second (@X, @Y, @Z)
```

Please let me know if this can be achivable this way? or there is any other better way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: first of all don't use max +1 for identity. you have Scope_Identity in Sql server. secondly is there any special requirement for ID with Some Prefix ?

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, you can use the [Output clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) to get the seq_No generated upon INSERT, and then UPDATE the ID.

Comment: I think use max + 1 is not a good way, if two clients execute this procedure concurrently, they get the same max number.

Comment: You can do it with SQL Server **2012** - use a `SEQUENCE` for each type of numbering you need (one for dogs, one for cats) and get the unique numbers from that sequence.